# Issues with Parity's send transactions and deploying contracts

Tags: transactions, parity, mac-osx, ropsten, pending-transactions

I am using the latest Parity client on Mac connected via WiFi (ping 25ms) on the Ropsten testnet. The chain is completely synced but my problem is that I can't post any transaction and also can't deploy any contracts. Pretty much everything that creates a transaction just isn't confirmed by the network. I am now waiting for more than ten minutes.

Any suggestions on what the problem might be? Is there a problem with the Ropsten testnet? The console output looks normal and I didn't have any problems to post transactions in the past.

Best regards,Lars

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that my issue was only limited to one account. So the private key of this very account got corrupted and is rendered unusable.

Parity should really give you more information about whether or not the transaction could be posted to the network. Obviously without the key it is impossible to start the transaction.

Parity just got stuck in the screen "Waiting for confirmation".